# Newlines being outputted actually as "\n"

Tags: c, string, while-loop, newline

This is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char userString[500];
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;

   while(x < 1 && (!(userString[0] == 'q'))){
      printf("Enter input string:\n");
      fgets(userString,500,stdin);
      for(int i = 0; i < strlen(userString);++i){
         if(userString[i] == ','){
            ++x; 
         }
      }
      if(x < 1){
         printf("Error: No comma in string."); 
         printf("\n");
      }   
   }
```

This is what is being outputted:

```
b'Enter input string:\nError: No comma in string.\nEnter input string:\nError: No comma in string.\nEnter input string:\nError: No comma in string.\nEnter input string:
```

This is the desired output:

```
Enter input string:
Error: No comma in string.

Enter input string:
Error: No comma in string.

Enter input string:
Error: No comma in string.

Enter input string:
```

The goal of the program is to get a string with a comma as input, and if there is no comma in the string, to keep prompting the user until they enter "q".I have not even the slightest clue why this could be happening. Would appreciate advice.

Comment: The output you've shown (`b'whatever'`) looks like a Python raw `bytes` string. Are you somehow running this program from a Python script?

Comment: How are you running it? The "b'" is there?

Comment: I might be, I'm running it in a web-browser on the website for my textbook.

Comment: The output you show reflects no input to the program. You cannot pass input as arguments to the program, your program takes input on `stdin`. Always have a compiler locally, for windows (if you don't want to download Gigabytes of VS) you can download MinGW for free, or worst case you can download the Windows Debug Toolkit for windows which is less than 1G an comes with the full (old) VS10 command line compiler c89, but much smaller than a full VS community download). That way you are not complicating coding with someone else's web widget.

Comment: in your if statements add \n to first printf and your problem is solved

Comment: *"I'm running it in a web-browser on the website for my textbook."* This is the problem. That website apparently sucks.